# Installing Packages from a 3rd Party Repository with FAI

Tags: automation, provisioning, fai

### Problem

I want to install [Docker CE](https://www.docker.com/community-edition) on a Debian Stretch system using [Fully Automatic Installation (FAI)](http://fai-project.org/). The official Docker documentation recommends that you [install Docker using their package repository](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-using-the-repository). I'm not sure how do this with FAI.

### Docker Installation Instructions

The given instructions for installing Docker are as follows.

1. Install packages to allow `apt` to use a repository over HTTPS:

```
sudo apt-get -y install \
apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
gnupg2 \
software-properties-common
```

2. Add Docker's official GPG key to APT:

```
curl \
-fsSL \
https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg \
| sudo apt-key add -
```

3. Add the Docker repository to APT:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
"deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"
```

4. Update the APT package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

5. Install the `docker-ce` package:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

### Solution Attempt

I decided to create an FAI class called `DOCKER` for this installation.

First I create the following hook for the `DOCKER` class (`/srv/fai/config/hooks/repository.DOCKER`):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install required packages for `add-apt-repository` utility
sudo apt-get install \
apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
gnupg2 \
software-properties-common

# Add the Docker repository
sudo add-apt-repository \
"deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"
```

Next I download the Docker repository public key and placed it in the FAI package configuration directory at the following path:

```
/srv/fai/config/package_config/DOCKER.asc
```

Then I create the following package configuration file for the `DOCKER` class (`/srv/fai/config/package_config/DOCKER`):

```
# Install Docker CE (Community Edition)
PACKAGES install
docker-ce
```

Finally I perform a dirinstall/chroot installation using the `DOCKER` class:

```
sudo fai \
--verbose \
--cfdir '/etc/fai' \
--class 'FAIBASE DEBIAN STRETCH DOCKER' \
--cspace 'file:///srv/fai/config' \
dirinstall 'docker'
```

Then I enter the chroot environment to check whether or not the installation was successful:

```
sudo chroot docker
```

Unfortunately when I check for `docker` it does not appear to be installed:

> ```
> root@faiserver:/# which docker
> root@faiserver:/# dpkg -l | grep -i docker
> ```

Checking the log files for evidence of the `docker-ce` package yields the following:

> ```
> root@faiserver:/# grep -Fir docker-ce /var/log/fai/faiserver/last/fai.log 
> WARNING: These unknown packages are removed from the installation list: docker-ce
> ```

I also look for evidence that the `add-apt-repository` command was executed, but don't find any:

> ```
> root@faiserver:/# grep -Firl add-apt /var/log/fai
> root@faiserver:/#
> ```

However I am able to verify that the key was added to APT successfully:

> ```
> root@faiserver:/# apt-key list 2>/dev/null | grep -i -B2 -A1 docker
> pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
>       9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
> uid           [ unknown] Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
> sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]
> ```

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?