# Actions Performed During FAI Repository Task Do Not Persist

Tags: automation, provisioning, fai

### Question

My hook script for the repository task (see the [list of FAI tasks](https://fai-project.org/fai-guide/#_a_id_tasks_a_the_list_of_tasks)) doesn't seem to be having an effect on the final state of installation. Why not? Is this the expected behavior? If so, why? And what, if anything, can I do to work around this restriction?

### Background

I'm trying to use FAI to install Docker CE from the Docker package repository (see [Installing Packages from a 3rd Party Repository with FAI](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/installing-packages-from-a-3rd-party-repository-with-fai)). Following the official instructions, I'm trying to use the `add-apt-repository` utility to add the package repository to the APT repository index. In order to get the `add-apt-repository` utility I'm trying to install the `software-properties-common` package. My plan was to use a hook script for the repository phase to install `software-properties-common` and then use `add-apt-repository` to add the Docker repository.

### Solution Attempt

I created the following repository-task hook script for a `SOFTPROPCOMM` class:

```
#!/bin/bash

# /srv/fai/config/hooks/repository.SOFTPROPCOMM

# Print command
echo apt-get install software-properties-common

# Execute command
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Then I perform a `dirinstall` to [create a chroot environment](http://fai-project.org/fai-guide/#_a_id_dirinstall_a_creating_chroot_and_virtualization_environments):

```
sudo fai \
--verbose \
--cfdir '/etc/fai' \
--class 'SOFTPROPCOMM' \
--cspace 'file:///srv/fai/config' \
dirinstall 'softpropcomm' \
| tee fai-softpropcomm.log
```

Then I enter the chroot environment:

```
sudo chroot softpropcomm
```

and from inside the chroot environment I check for the presence of the `add-apt-repository` application:

```
which add-apt-repository
```

and also for the presence of the `software-properties-common` package:

```
dpkg -l | grep -Fi software-properties-common
```

Neither the application nor the package appear to be present. So I try manually installing the package (still from within the chroot):

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

The installation proceeds as expected for a new package (one that isn't already installed on the system) and after the package installation completes I can verify that the `add-apt-repository` application has been successfully installed. This seems to suggest that repository-task hook script did not execute successfully. So I and look at my log file (back on the host - outside of the chroot):

```
cat fai-softpropcomm.log \
| grep -Fi -B1 -A2 software-properties-common
```

This produces the following output:

```
Calling hook: repository.SOFTPROPCOMM
apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
software-properties-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 86 not upgraded.
repository.SOFTPROPCOMM OK.
```

This seems to suggest that the package was already installed prior to the execution of my hook script, which is doubly confusing.

### Debugging Attempt

In order to test what was happening I added a command to the repository-task hook script to write to a new file. Here is the new hook script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# /srv/fai/config/hooks/repository.SOFTPROPCOMM

echo "Testing repository-task hook script"
echo "Writing to file /test"
echo "Success" > /test
echo "Checking contents of /test"
cat /test
```

The output from the installation process includes the following block for the repository-task hook:

```
[...]
Calling hook: repository.SOFTPROPCOMM
Testing repository-task hook script
Writing to file /test
Checking contents of /test
Success
repository.SOFTPROPCOMM OK.
[...]
```

But then when I enter the chroot the file isn't there.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?